# How to querySelectorAll by className and specific dataset value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My next question is how I am able to querySelectorAll elements which have a certain className and a dataset attribute assigned to false.
The following example works as I want it to.

```js
   const huecosDisponibles = document.querySelectorAll('.date[data-waiting="false"]');
console.log(huecosDisponibles);
```

```html
<div class="dates" data-waiting="false">hola</div>
<div class="dates" data-waiting="false">hola</div>
<div class="dates" data-waiting="false">hola</div>
<div class="dates" data-waiting="false">hola</div>
<div class="dates" data-waiting="false">hola</div>
<div class="dates" data-waiting="false">hola</div>
<div class="dates" data-waiting="true">hola</div>
<div class="dates" data-waiting="false">hola</div>
```

Nevertheless, I am trying to apply the same selection technique after performing an Ajax request in a C# razor page and it doesn't happen.
The  function which contains the ajax request sets some of the boxes to true or false.

In my case, I have to select the ones that they have the dataset attribute to false.
I assume that the problem may lie in the `document.ready` state.
I tried moving my variable after the ajax request is completed and still I am getting
the same error again and again:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: dates is not defined
```

If anyone has any advice which can help me solve this problem, that would be really grateful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like a variable scope issue, make sure you're referring the variable in a scope accessible to the scope the variable was declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.ready` doesn't fire after AJAX completion or anytime when nodes inserted to DOM.

Be sure, that you have appended new nodes to DOM.
JS code of AJAX would be helpful.